# How to write java TCP object transmission for multiple clients

Tags: java, multithreading, sockets, tcp

I'm writing a primitive Graphical MUD-like online game using only the Java standard library - just Swing and TCP sockets (for school and for fun). The game has a server (a spare laptop in my closet) that accepts TCP connections from players and takes in objects (using ObjectInputStream) - chat strings and dropped items and such - and uses those objects to make changes to the virtual world that are then forwarded to the other players.

Initially, I thought I could make each and every player connect to the same TCP port on my server (port 5010) by having my server's main thread listen for each of their connections using a loop, like so...

```
while (true)
{
        //get new connection
    serversocket = new ServerSocket(5010);
    socket = serversocket.accept();
    serversocket.close();
        //proceed to log in player using their computer's host name.
}
```

Then I pass each new player's TCP socket connection to a thread dedicated to that player's object input and output, like so:

```
new_thread = new Thread(new Server_Input_Thread(main_thread_socket));
```

When I'm debugging, I test the game by running both the server side application and the client side application from my other laptop and connect through "localhost".

But I'm having problems. I can't get past IOExceptions such as Bind exceptions and "java.net.SocketException: socket closed" when listening for a new connection (on port 5010) after the initial connection (also on port 5010) has been made.

Apparently the way I'm doing it isn't working and perhaps I'll need to assign each player a unique port number rather than have every player try to connect to port 5010, or maybe it's because I'm using my coding laptop as both a client and a server.

Unfortunately for me, I have no idea what I'm doing - I just declared Computer Science as my major one semester ago. Please explain how to structure the network connections for such a virtual world and avoid the IOExceptions that occur immediately after the initial connection between the client application and the server, as the server is starting to once again listen for a new connection on port 5010 on the main thread.

Comment: Well you are closing the socket straight after opening it. That is your first problem.

Comment: have you tried any of the oracle network tutorials?

Comment: Yes but it was more of a skim than a thorough read.

Comment: Besides the little technical details, I'm curious about whether there are any big gaping holes in the overall design. Like for example if TCP is a bad design choice for sending out data to many different players at the same time - perhaps I should be using UDP Multisocket instead. Or perhaps UDP would have been a bad choice because one way UDP signals are less likely to make it through a wireless modem and a firewall and TCP signals. Those sort of big, foreseeable problems.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this

```
serversocket = new ServerSocket(5010);

while (true)
{
    socket = serversocket.accept();


    //proceed to log in player using their computer's host name.
} 
serversocket.close();
```

I am not going to show you the other problems you are going to face but this should at least get you going.

Comment: But I read that the ServerSocket is only used for making the connection.

Comment: A server socket stays open the whole time. It is listening for connections. A client can connect to a listening sockets. A server cannot connect to a client socket. That is how TCP works.

Comment: Oh I see. The ServerSocket object doesn't just create a single connection and then get replaced by a new one each time a new connection is needed.

Comment: Welcome to the rabbit hole. Yes you are correct. Post some more if you need answers.